# Automate AngularJS UI-Grid using UFT

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to know if anyone tried automating the UI-Grid earlier named as NG-Grid using UFT.
I am using UFT 12.02 patch 2 version and when I spy on grids in my application which is using UI-Grid, it recognizes it as webelement and I am not able to use functions like getcelldata, click cell etc.

- The best thing is if UFT can directly recognize it as a grid or table.
- If not, then one option is to write our own logic using extensibility but that I would like to use a last option as it would require lot of handling, scrolldown operation and then reading dom again and again and many more.
- Other option I would like to use is using extensibility and calling the UI-Grid APIs using javascript to perform operaitons. I have used it to automate JQGrids and if anyone can suggest how to call APIs of UI-Grid, that would be great.

I would appreciate any reply on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the best thing is to get the elements class and using the index see how long the element's index goes and how it identifies the elements by using highlight method . getting the index count, write logic to capture them in data table and once the indexed is reached to the highest (you can know if the previous index worked but the next index throwing error the last index is the max index for the elements. now you have to highlight the last element you found. it will load the new grids duplicating some old grid as you will get some old grid by giving index 0 or something. now you have to figure out which index is giving you the next grid by using highlight and get the index to capture the data form the next load. again highlight the last grid to re load and use the index you found as new record to capture . repeat them again by for loop.

Last load it will not load the grid as you found as before as they may contain full set or less. here the code may record some duplicate using the previous logic.
Now you need to remove the duplicate records by using some code.

The following is done as all the columns and rows have same properties but different index . The record the page loads is 69 for the first time but 2nd time it loads 89 with 25 duplicated record. This may be different with your page. My page contains 5 columns.

```
Dim HighlitedElement, PreviousHighlitedElement, StartingElement, EndingElement
Set cpLookup= browser("name:=Legal Entity Search - QA1").page("title:=Legal Entity Search - QA1")
PreviousHighlitedElement=""
datatable.AddSheet ("CounterParty_Lookup").AddParameter "Name",""
datatable.AddSheet ("CounterParty_Lookup").AddParameter "LE_Number",""
datatable.GetSheet("CounterParty_Lookup").AddParameter "Oracle_Number",""        
datatable.GetSheet("CounterParty_Lookup").AddParameter "Effective_Date",""
datatable.GetSheet("CounterParty_Lookup").AddParameter "Termination_Date",""
CurrentColumn=1
CurrentRow=1
StartingElement=0
EndingElement=69
For j = 0 To 100 Step 1

    If not j = 0 and DuplicateRecord=false Then
        StartingElement=0+25
        EndingElement=44+20+25    
    End If
    arrayElement=0
    For i = StartingElement To EndingElement Step 1
        datatable.GetSheet("CounterParty_Lookup").SetCurrentRow(CurrentRow)

        Select Case CurrentColumn

            Case 1
                If cpLookup.webelement("html id:=","html tag:=DIV", "index:="&i,"class:=ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope").exist(2) Then
                    datatable.Value ("Name", "CounterParty_Lookup")=cpLookup.webelement("html id:=","html tag:=DIV", "index:="&i,"class:=ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope").getroproperty("outertext")

                       CurrentColumn=CurrentColumn+1 
                                      Else
                    notfound = true
                    Exit for
                End If

            Case 2
                datatable.Value ("LE_Number", "CounterParty_Lookup")=cpLookup.webelement("html id:=","html tag:=DIV", "index:="&i,"class:=ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope").getroproperty("outertext")    
                CurrentColumn=CurrentColumn+1

            Case 3
                datatable.Value ("Oracle_Number", "CounterParty_Lookup")=cpLookup.webelement("html id:=","html tag:=DIV", "index:="&i,"class:=ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope").getroproperty("outertext")    
                CurrentColumn=CurrentColumn+1

            Case 4
                datatable.Value ("Effective_Date", "CounterParty_Lookup")=cpLookup.webelement("html id:=","html tag:=DIV", "index:="&i,"class:=ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope").getroproperty("outertext")    
                CurrentColumn=CurrentColumn+1

            Case 5
                datatable.Value ("Termination_Date", "CounterParty_Lookup")=cpLookup.webelement("html id:=","html tag:=DIV", "index:="&i,"class:=ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope").getroproperty("outertext")    
                CurrentColumn=1
                CurrentRow=CurrentRow+1
        End Select

    Next
    HighlitedElement=cpLookup.webelement("html id:=","html tag:=DIV", "index:="&i-5,"class:=ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope").getroproperty("outertext")
    cpLookup.webelement("html id:=","html tag:=DIV", "index:="&i-5,"class:=ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope").highlight

        If HighlitedElement=PreviousHighlitedElement or notfound Then
              Exit for
        else
            PreviousHighlitedElement= HighlitedElement
        End If

Next
' (to indicate as duplicated record and get the exect count of the rows )

TotalInitialRows=datatable.GetSheet("CounterParty_Lookup").GetCurrentRow-1
CurrentRow=CurrentRow-20
DuplicatedRecord=0
'Msgbox TotalInitialRows
If TotalInitialRows > 20 Then

    For  eachrow= CurrentRow To TotalInitialRows Step 1

        datatable.GetSheet("CounterParty_Lookup").SetCurrentRow(eachrow)
        currentValue=datatable.Value ("Name", "CounterParty_Lookup")
        For totalRow = eachrow To TotalInitialRows Step 1
            newrow=totalRow+1
            datatable.GetSheet("CounterParty_Lookup").SetCurrentRow(newrow)
            ncurrentValue=datatable.Value ("Name", "CounterParty_Lookup")
            If ncurrentValue=currentValue and currentValue <> "DuplicatedRecord"  Then
                DuplicatedRecord=1+DuplicatedRecord
                   datatable.Value ("Name", "CounterParty_Lookup")="DuplicatedRecord"
                Exit for
            End If

        Next

    Next

End If

TotalRows=TotalInitialRows-DuplicatedRecord

Msgbox TotalRows
```